# Jquery defer: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to initialize a defer function within jquery, but in the console i read the same line error as the title:

```
Jquery defer: $ is not defined
```

here the script at the end of the page:

```
   <script defer> 
    var initSlider = function(){
        $('.c-carousel-elezioni').slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: false,
            prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>',
            nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>',
              responsive: [
                {
                  breakpoint: 1024,
                  settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true
                  }
                },
                {
                  breakpoint: 600,
                  settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                  }
                },
                {
                  breakpoint: 480,
                  settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                  }
                }
                // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
                // settings: "unslick"
                // instead of a settings object
              ]                
        });
    }

    deferVideo(initSlider());
</script>
```

Jquery is defined at the TOP of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../clientlibs_thirdparty/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" defer></script>

    <script>

if (typeof deferVideo === 'undefined'){
    var deferVideo = function(method) {  
        if (window.jQuery && $.skytg24) {
            method();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() { deferVideo(method) }, 100);
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

so i suppose is a related problem on script by itself.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you use Prototype?

Comment: Doesn't explain your issue, but worth noting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script: *defer* : This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also It all looks like you want to pass `deferVideo(initSlider)` function itself, not the result of its invocation (which is undefined)

Comment: And I've removed `jquery-deferred` and `deferred` tags since your question has nothing to do with either.

Comment: `Jquery is defined at the TOP of the page,` - But is it defined as $

Comment: can you show html where it include jquery?

Comment: Is your jquery include *also* set to `defer`?  If so, that's your problem combined with my earlier comment and link.

Comment: i've edited the question